# Accept incoming conversation (Lync)

Tags: wpf, toast, lync

I'm developing a WPF app, to add a new toast pop up to incoming calls, where i show information about the "caller". The thing is I have my toast working great, but I want to open the conversation (like when you click the real toast), I already got the event working (i mean when i click the toast)

Here is a list of thing that i already tried:

1. Modality.Accept();(foreach modality)
2. ConversationWindow.ShowContent();
3. (WIN+A) I tried to perform a SendKey but WIN key (or super) is not in the dictionary, i can emulate it with Ctrl+Esc plus A but doesn't work. (WIN+A accept conversation, Ctrl+Esc = WIN, Ctrl+Esc+A != WIN+A, i don't know why)

Hope you can understand me, English is no my native language

Comment: BTW, I don't care if is video, audio or just IM, i just need to open the conversation window

Comment: Are you writing this for Lync 2010 or 2013? The answer to your question will be very different based on which version you are supporting.